# PHP OOP: How to structure a Mapper that requires functionality from another Mapper

Tags: php, oop, datamapper

Lets say I have two objects, Category and Product:

**Category**

```
<?php class Category {
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
?>
```

**Product**

```
<?php class Product {
    private $name, $category;

    public function __construct(string $name, Category $category) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
}
?>
```

And I have a CategoryMapper that gets (and inserts/updates/deletes) Category-objects from the database:

**CategoryMapper**

```
<?php
class CategoryMapper {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function ofId($id) : ?Category {

        $query = 'SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);

        if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            return new Category($row['name']);
        }

        return null;

    }

    // Other methods
}
?>
```

I also need a ProductMapper, but the ProductMapper's `ofId()` method needs to return a Product object with a Category object inside of it.

**So now for my question: How should my ProductMapper be structured?**

**Option 1 - Pass ProductMapper a CategoryMapper in the constructor**

I suppose this could get quite large if CategoryMapper in turn requires yet another Mapper, and that Mapper requires yet another Mapper, and so forth.

```
<?php
class ProductMapper {
    private $pdo, $categoryMapper;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, CategoryMapper $categoryMapper) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->categoryMapper = $categoryMapper;
    }

    public function ofId($id) {

        $query = 'SELECT name, categoryId FROM product WHERE id = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);

        if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $category = $this->categoryMapper->ofId($row['categoryId']);
            return new Product($row['name'], $category);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
?>
```

**Option 2 - Have ProductMapper create a CategoryMapper in the method where it needs one**

If ProductMapper requires a lot of other Mappers, I might loose track here as to which Mappers are actually being used by the ProductMapper, because they're not listed in a single place but scattered throughout the code.

```
<?php
class ProductMapper {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function ofId($id) {

        $query = 'SELECT name, categoryId FROM product WHERE id = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);

        if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $categoryMapper = new CategoryMapper($this->pdo);
            $category = $categoryMapper->ofId($row['categoryId']);
            return new Product($row['name'], $category);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
?>
```

**Option 3 - Do not use the CategoryMapper and duplicate the build-a-category code in the ProductMapper**

This just leads to a lot of duplicate code (especially if the embedded objects get bigger or have objects embedded inside of them as well).

```
<?php
class ProductMapper {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function ofId($id) {

        $query = 'SELECT p.name as productName, c.name as categoryName FROM product p join category c on p.categoryId = c.id WHERE p.id = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);

        if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $category = new Category($row['categoryName']);
            return new Product($row['productName'], $category);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
?>
```

So how is this usually done?
Are there any other options I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The first method is the correct one. You should pass all dependencies as parameters in the constructor.

Long answer: The first method is the correct one, but it's a good practice to use some dependency injection container. It will take care of initializing objects and passing them as params to another objects. It will also make sure that only one object of each class is initialized. If you want something lightweight, you could go with [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com/) or, if you prefer something more configurable with many features, [Symfony's DependencyInjection component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a singleton method in the CategoryMapper class like below

```
public static $instance = null;    
public static function getInstance() {
     if (self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new self();
     }

     return self::$instance;
}
```

The call to ProductMapper is as below

```
public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    $this->categoryMapper = CategoryMapper::getInstance();
}
```